# JQuery Sortable with dynamic DIV

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page that implements jQuery draggable, droppable, and sortable.  It contains rows of div's, an "Add Line" button, and an image icon that can be dragged onto any div row that causes a modal window to display allowing an image to be placed onto the row.  Everything works great...except:

I use jQuery sortable to allow the rows to be re-arranged.  As dragging occurs (constrained to the y-axis), the div that the dragged div is being dragged over, and placed after if it is dropped, is colored gray.  This works great, except when there are images in a DIV, causing the dragged DIV to have a much greater height than an empty div.  It doesn't seem to track properly, as demomnstrated by how the rows turn to and from gray.

Here is some JQuery code:

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
    over: function(event,ui)
    {
        var ElementOver = $(event.target);
        var DraggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
        var IDofDraggedElement = DraggedElement.attr("id");             

        ElementOver.css("background-color","lightgray");
    },
    out: function(event,ui)
    {
        var ElementOver = $(event.target);
        ElementOver.css("background-color","");
    },
    drop: function(event,ui)
    {
        DropObject(event,ui); //This handles Ajax activity  
        var ElementOver = $(event.target);
        ElementOver.css("background-color","");
    }
});             


$("#lines").sortable({
    handle: '.iconmove',
    axis: 'y',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    helper: 'clone'         
});
```

and here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<div id="linecontainer" class="w3-card-4 w3-padding">
    <div id="lines">
        <cfoutput query="qFormLines" group="formlineid">
            <div  class="w3-row w3-padding" style="width:80%" id="line#formlineid#">
                <div class="w3-col w3-center  l1 m1 s1">
                    <img id="moveicon#formlineid#" class="iconmove" src="_images/updown24.png" title="Move Line" >
                </div>
                <div class="dropzone w3-padding w3-col w3-border l11 m11 s11" id="zone#formlineid#"   >
                    <cfoutput>
                        <cfif imagefile NEQ "">
                            <img id="formitem#formitemid#" class="w3-border" src="_images/#imagefile#"   >
                        </cfif>
                    </cfoutput>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle I created, although it doesn't quite work the same as my local source code:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnu4Lboy/21/)

Comment: Hi, it is not clear as to what exactly is your problem and what solution do you want? If you can separate it out stating the problem and expected output it will be great!

Comment: Do you want all the divs to be the same height while dragging whether or not they have an image or not?

Comment: Try my old example https://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/KZeBq/ there is a connectToSortable thingy.. provided by id of the element.

Comment: Berker - Doesn't really help since I can't drag/sort an existing div.

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, just change the JQuery Droppable method's option - **Tolerance** from its default 'intersect' to 'touch'. It will allow you to see the effect whenever the draggable overlaps the droppable by any amount of touching:

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
  // Change the tolerance to 'touch'
  tolerance: "touch",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    var ElementOver = $(event.target);
    var DraggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
    var IDofDraggedElement = DraggedElement.attr("id");

    console.log(IDofDraggedElement);

    //if (IDofDraggedElement.indexOf("imageicon") == 0) //MOVING A LINE
    ElementOver.css("background-color", "lightgray");
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    var ElementOver = $(event.target);

    ElementOver.css("background-color", "");
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var ElementOver = $(event.target);

    ElementOver.css("background-color", "");
  }
});


$("#lines").sortable({
  handle: '.iconmove',
  axis: 'y',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  helper: 'clone'

});
```

The droppable's tolerance has four options:

"fit − Draggable covers the droppable element in full.

intersect − Draggable overlaps the droppable element at least 50% in both directions.

pointer − Mouse pointer overlaps the droppable element.

touch − Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount of touching."

Quote from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_droppable.htm

Comment: I have tried all the tolerance options.  Nothing works the way it "should".  I have decided to just go with separate up and down icons that can be clicked on to move the rows one level at a time.